# Spatie Laravel-activitylog causedBy, performedOn with Logging model

Tags: php, laravel-5, activitylog

I am using [this package for activity logging in laravel](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-activitylog/tree/v1)
I am able to do logging from controller but, I want to do it using Model.

I read this useful information from the [official documentation](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-activitylog/v1/advanced-usage/logging-model-events#logging-model-events)

but, it doesnt store subject id, type and causer id, type. I can store it from controller as

```
activity()
   ->causedBy($userModel)
   ->performedOn($someContentModel)
   ->log('edited');
```

How to do this from model? Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. Now I got your question. If you want to performance in Modal.
Below is my sample code in my `Business` model class.

```
 protected static function boot()
    {
        //to log what field update
        static::updating(function ($business) {
            $changes = $business->isDirty() ? $business->getDirty() : false;
            if($changes)
            {
                foreach($changes as $attr => $value)
                {
                    activity()
                        ->performedOn($business)
                        ->causedBy(auth()->user())
                        ->withProperties(['business_name' => $business->name, 'which field updated' => $business->getDirty()])
                        ->log('Business Field <span class="text-green">Updated</span>  - '.$business->name);

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

For the Subject's info you have to manually add in, below is my sample code how I store it in controller. I hope you can get some reference.

```
activity() 
    ->performedOn($business)
    ->causedBy(auth()->user())
    ->withProperties(['business_name' => $business->name)
    ->log('Business <span class="text-green">Updated</span>  - '.$business->name);
```

DB Records as below:

[image: db record]

```
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | log_name | description                                                     | subject_id | subject_type | causer_id | causer_type | properties                          | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | default  | Business <span class="text-green">Updated</span> - Companies 10 |         10 | App\Business |         1 | App\User    | {"business_name":"Best Restaurant"} | 2017-08-04 14:58:06 | 2017-08-04 14:58:06 |
+----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: thanks for stoping by, yeah I am have to add manually but I didn't get the proper usage example inside model. Have you got any idea? :) I don't want to add my logging code in controller methods. so, using model will be quick and easy

Comment: what do you mean you didn't get proper usage? I update my db record in above answer. And just to make sure you are using the same version like me. I am using v2. But the link your share is v1.

Comment: Thanks I have got some ideas from this

Comment: If possible please share your solution and mark as completed.